# .NET Workflow issue

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I am calling my WF:

```
        Workflow1 wf = new Workflow1()
                           {
                               ChildrenOption = true,
                               Market = "english",
                               Server = new Uri("http://mysite"),
                               SPTags = dataToUpdate,
                           };
        WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new Workflow1());
```

But for some reason I am getting this exception, why? Any other way how I can invoke wf to avoid this problem?

```
Values must be bound to a non-null expression before ParallelForEach activity 
'ParallelForEach<KeyValuePair<Tuple<String,String,String>,ZalupaTag>>' can be used.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Workflow1 has a ParallelForEach activity in it for which you did not provide a collection to the Values property.